# Subset from Date in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I have uploaded data in R called `prepaid` and am trying to extract a subset based on the `SnapShot` date which is of the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`.

The coding I have coded so far is a below:

```
Date2 <- as.Date(as.character(prepaid$SnapshotDate),"%d/%m/%y")
SubsetDate <- subset(prepaid,Date2 > as.Date("14/02/2019"))
```

However the output given is the snapshot date is 31/05/2018 which shouldn't be case as I want the subset where the SnapshotDate = 14/02/2019

Comment: `as.Date("14/02/2019", "%d/%m/%Y")`, note the uppercase for Y

Comment: You can find the explanations for the characters with `?strptime` (helppage for strptime); %Y = year with century, %y = year without century.

Answer (score 0):

With `base`, you have to change `%y` by `%Y`

```
Date2 <- as.Date(as.character(prepaid$SnapshotDate),"%d/%m/%Y")
SubsetDate <- subset(prepaid, Date2 > as.Date("14/02/2019", "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

You can can also use the `lubridate` package

```
library(lubridate)

Date2 <- dmy(prepaid$SnapshotDate)
SubsetDate <- subset(prepaid, Date2 > dmy("14/02/2019"))
```